# QGIS 3.4 Layout composer tool bars are too small to see

Tags: qgis, layouts

I'm at a loss. I just updated to QGIS 3.4, and it was working fine, but now my Layout window has only tiny tool bars and the move item content tool is non-existent. Can anyone help?  The same thing seems to be happening in the georeferencer window as well

[image]

Comment: QGIS 3.14? Do you mean 2.14 or 3.4 or ..? Did you check your settings within "View --> Toolbars / Panels"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, sorry it is 3.4. I updated from 2.14. I did also toggle the view toolbars but it just turned them off and turned them back on again in the same place

Comment: The toolbars aren't "too small to see." They don't have any buttons on them at all. That's a serious bug. I would first try re-installing QGIS. If that doesn't fix the issue, make a bug report on https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that